Error in migration from System.Oracle.Client to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client
I am trying to migrate my dotnet project in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client and have added this dll in project reference. And connectionstring in
App.config is also updated with new provider name Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client
Connection string are maintained through Settings.settings
but when I update One of the .XSD file with Provider and save then Dataset.Designer.cs is not getting generated.
I did some google searching and got to know that settings.settings does not support Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client so you should remove connection string from settings.settings and write connection string in app.config and write .cs code to fetch that string
but I doubt by doing this whether I would be able to use that connection string in my .XSD file.
